# Jenkins GitHub OAuth plugin not visible in securityRealm

Tags: github, jenkins, oauth

I set up jenkins and I would like to use Github authenticator. Plug-in was installed properly but in Global Security I can't find Github oauth option in Security Realm and Authorization Strategy.
Is there any dependency for the plug-in (besides these installed automatically) or something?

Answer (score 0):

In plug-ins I had every needed plug-in enabled but still in folder $JENKINS_HOME/plugins there was file `github-api.jpi.disabled`.
Remove the file and restart Jenkins.
Now Github Anthentication Plugin is visible in Security Realm